# Limitations in using FLEX as a DMFT solver

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, research-level, perturbation-theory

When using the fluctuating exchange approximation (FLEX) as a dynamical mean field theory (DMFT) solver, [Kotliar, et al.](http://rmp.aps.org/abstract/RMP/v78/i3/p865_1) (p. 898) suggest that it is only reliable for when the interaction strength, $U$, is less than half the bandwidth.  How would one verify this?  Also, is there a general technique for establishing this type of limit?

To clarify, DMFT is an approximation to the Anderson impurity model, and FLEX is a perturbative expansion in the interaction strength about the band, low interaction strength limit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The criterion you mention is roughly the threshold for the formation of the Coulomb gap in the Hubbard model or the local moment in the Anderson model. It is a common break-down region for many approaches starting from one of the limits (insulator/local moments versus conductor/mixed valence).

For perturbation theory in $U$, see the [PRB 36, 675 (1986)](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v36/i1/p675_1) by Horvatić et al. and references to and form that paper.  A more comprehensive discussion can be found in the 
monograph by [Hewson](http://books.google.com/books?id=fPzgHneNFDAC). As far as I remember, perturbation in $U$ on the level of self-energy does not give the expected exponential dependence on $U$ for the Kondo temperature.

Unfortunately, I don't know specifics of FLEX method to help you in more detail.

Comment: What level of detail would you require? Mostly, I'm looking for what is needed to improve/clarify the question.

Comment: The comment was more about the limitations of my knowledge rather gaps in your question. I know only the general principles of DMFT, never implemented it myself, and, in particular, do not know what FLEX is. Just sharing an idea coming from my non-DMFT experience with strongly correlated models.

Comment: FLEX is the expansion about the interaction strength, i.e. the conductor/mixed valence end of the spectrum. Do you have any references that illustrate the break-down region?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add a reference. You can see form the graphs that they choose moderate U's. For more details, see their references and the monograph by [Hewson](http://books.google.com/books?id=fPzgHneNFDAC&lpg=PR11&ots=xTPleU6qep&dq=Hewson%20heavy%20fermion&lr&pg=PR11#v=onepage&q=Hewson%20heavy%20fermion&f=false). As far as I remember, perturbation in $U$ on the level of self-energy does not give the exponential dependence on $U$ for the Kondo temperature